# Jest/fetch-mock ignoring setTimeout inside Promise

Tags: javascript, jestjs

I built a function which will repeat a HTTP request 3 times every 1500ms if the the status is 5xx.

```
const fetchRetry = (url: string, options = {}, retries = 3, timeout = 1500) => {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    fetch(url, options).then((res) => {
      if (res.ok) return resolve(res);

      if (retries > 0 && res.status >= 500 && res.status < 600) {
        setTimeout(() => {
          resolve(fetchRetry(url, options, retries - 1, timeout));
        }, timeout);
      } else {
        return resolve(res);
      }
    });
  });
};

export default fetchRetry;
```

It works just fine on the browser, but is causing a lot of tests to fail.

This is an example of a test that I have:

```
fetchMock.postOnce("/my-api", {
  status: 503,
});

const expectedActions = [
  {
   itemRef: "sample",
  },
];

return store
  .dispatch(myAction.findRef(itemRef))
  .then(() => {
    expect(store.getActions()).toEqual(expectedActions);
  });
```

Basically I'm testing my code using `jest` and `fetch-mock`, as you can see, I'm mocking the api request and I'm waiting `myAction.findRef(itemRef)` (Promise) to be fulfilled.

I'm always receiving: `Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within the 5000 ms timeout specified by jest.setTimeout.Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within the 5000 ms timeout specified by jest.setTimeout.Error:`.

If I remove `setTimeout` it will work. Which is bizarre.

I also tried to increment the jest.setTimeout.Timeout but with no luck.

Any ideas?